# Why isn't there any Cryptocurrency for fuzzing well-known softwares?

Tags: fuzzing, bitcoin

Looks like automated fuzzing is a great idea to find security vulnerabilities, bugs: http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2017/q1/471 , ex.: syzkaller ( https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13705833 )

For the Cryptocurrency part.. why aren't the great resources of generating coins invested in ex.: fuzzing? I mean people could get coins for fuzzing, of course 100% automated (to get coins I mean the Cryptocurrencies algorithm works based on the fuzzing amount, more fuzzing, more coins due to the algorithm, so CPU isn't wasted, rather used for fuzzing).

(if a crash/bug is found via fuzzing, of course human interaction needed, but that is not the question, the bug would be automatically reported to a central place, reward the people who fixes the bug)

**Q:** How could this be done? Any ideas? How could an algorithm create coins for using CPU time for fuzzing softwares?

Comment: There are many companies that offer bug bounties.  They don't care how the bug hunters detect them.  If you want to fuzz a Google product to find a bug and report it for a reward, go ahead.  If you want to join with a dozen other people to fuzz 12x faster, and split the reward 12 ways, you are free to go ahead and do that, too. If you want to set up a website to conscript volunteers from across the web to fuzz a product, and if you make money at it, congratulations!

Comment: You need to consider that in order to fuzz some service, you need a non production (non critical) service running at the other end. Now imagine the horsepower required to run such services and have them handle [Proof of work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system) sized loads. The idea that you are proposing is lovely, but not at all practical (or possible) in my opinion.